# Does dbt support "regions" in the model DAG?

Tags: dbt

We've been using `dbt` at my company for a few months, and it's starting to get hard to think through the `dag` that is emerging.

Does `dbt` support "regions"

ie. something visually similar to [image]

That groups "models" by some user defined boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this exact concept exists, but...
You could try to implement tags with certain grouping of models. Then you can look at lineage using a selector involving specific tags.